# Ran most recent update, now my Youtube videos are gone

Tags: flash, youtube

Strangely I can still watch those I downloaded to my HD
but Youtube video field on site is a white slate. Do I need to reinstall Flash and how do I do it?

Comment: You don't need Flash for YouTube. It defaults to HTML 5.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar... well, whatever, is not working. Can you give me any tips or pointers?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 PP

Comment: The update installed FF 50.1.0 which might be too powerful for 12.04. Maybe I should migrate back to a lower version? Unfortunately I ran the tweaks janitor so my earlier versions are gone.

Comment: Do you possibly have a plugin installed which makes it default to Flash? (If you have, disable it.) Another thought is [bug #1643467](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1643467). (12.04 is old. Thought of upgrading?)

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. I refreshed FF and that restored Youtube videos but now FB videos don't play! Can you tell me how to upgrade 12.04? I've been getting prompts to do that but the source is untrusted.

Comment: Upgrading to a more recent release is quite a different topic. If you need advice about that, please ask a new question. But do some research first. There is a lot written about it.